# Data not inserting laravel mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to insert data in mysql database in laravel, default table users, while submitting the form is refreshing and data is not inserting to database, no error is showing. I dont know where is the problem. My code is given.

register.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Teacher Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="tname" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="tname" value="{{ old('tname') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('tname'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('tname') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="fname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Father Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="fname" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('fname'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('fname') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="domicile" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Domicile') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="domicile" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('domicile') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="domicile" value="{{ old('domicile') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('domicile'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('domicile') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="string" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('C.N.I.C') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nic" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('nic') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="nic" value="{{ old('nic') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('nic'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('nic') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Phone') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="phone" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Official E-Mail') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('off_email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                                <a href="{{url('auth/google')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Register With Google</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Model is User and its code is given below.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'tname','fname','domicile','nic','phone','email','off_email', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

This is the code of auth/RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'tname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'fname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'domicile' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'nic' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'phone' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'off_email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'tname' => $data['tname'],
            'fname' => $data['fname'],
            'domicile' => $data['domicile'],
            'nic' => $data['nic'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'off_email' => $data['off_email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

The form does not showing any error while submiting it is just refreshing, no message that data is inserted or not, while when i check users table there will no any row,..Any body can help me please,

Comment: Show your routes file

Comment: Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Comment: Add this in your question.

Comment: And you haven't defined your register route

Comment: is register route not defined by default in Auth::routes();??

Comment: I have not created new view but updated the folder which is by default provided us by laravel

Comment: What update you have made ?

Comment: I have inserting new columns in user migration, and in register view, also in register controller

Comment: OT: Minor annoyances: your label's `for` attributes need to target an `id` of an input element. `id`s should be unique in the document, which yours aren't.

Comment: should I remove it?